# How much buoyant force to pull a plastic cube from under a tank of water in to the water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, water, buoyancy

I'm having a hard time to understand how many same size black cubes would be in order to pull up the bottom black cube in to the water. I know water level is important but I believe there must be a way to calculate this.  please refer to the picture for clarification
[image]

the black cube is out of the water and I'm trying to pull the whole cube up in to the water.
thanks for all your responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Water level is not important for buoyancy it is merely a function of density. Hence to know how many black cubes. Determine the net force of one of the submerged cubes (net force = (fluid density X gravity X volume submerged)- weight of the cube) and solve for the force applied by gravity on the other cube that is dangling below(same weight as the others). All you need is a multiple of floating cubes that exerts a greater force than gravity does on the dangling cube.

Also have a great day